# Yii2 dosamigos Ckeditor Language Direction

Tags: php, yii2, yii-widgets

In Yii2 Ckeditor , I am using

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
```

this extension for showing ckeditor in form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cmsdetails_ar')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic', 'contentsLangDirection'=>'rtl' 
    ]) ?>
```

I have add a additional option  'contentsLangDirection'=>'rtl'  to show arabic text .
But contentsLangDirection is not working this extension ,

Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cmsdetails_ar')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic',  'clientOptions' => ['contentsLangDirection'=>'rtl']
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: What a coincidence? Both person having same name as *Biju S* and both belongs to *Trivandrum*. And, both joined Stack Overflow *2 years, 4 months*